# Excel embeded IF statements - too many arguments error

Tags: excel, if-statement, ms-office

I have the following series of if statements and I'm getting the error that there's too many arguments. I've checked some other posts with similar problems but can't see their problems within my statement. Essentially if the cell B2 contains a number month, I need it to perform a vlookup on a certain spreadsheet:

```
=if(B2=1,VLOOKUP(G2,'[Jan_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Sheet1'!$L$1:$U$4236,10,FALSE),if(B2=2,VLOOKUP(G2,'[feb_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$2:$U$4214,10,FALSE), if(B2=3,vlookup(G2,'[mar_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4262,10,FALSE), if(B2=4,VLOOKUP(G2,'[apr_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4262,10,FALSE),if(B2=5,'[may_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4234,10,FALSE),if(B2=6,VLOOKUP(G2,'[jun_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4310,10,FALSE),if(B2=7,VLOOKUP(G2,'[jul_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4322,10,FALSE),if(B2=8,VLOOKUP(G2,'[aug_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4288,10,FALSE)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I get stuck in nested function hell, like this one, I like to break up the formula with some white space. It makes spotting the issues very easy:

```
=if(
    B2=1,
    VLOOKUP(G2,'[Jan_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Sheet1'!$L$1:$U$4236,10,FALSE),
    if(
        B2=2,
        VLOOKUP(G2,'[feb_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$2:$U$4214,10,FALSE), 
        if(
            B2=3,
            vlookup(G2,'[mar_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4262,10,FALSE), 
            if(
                B2=4,
                VLOOKUP(G2,'[apr_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4262,10,FALSE),
                if(
                    B2=5,
                    '[may_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4234,10,FALSE),
                    if(
                        B2=6,
                        VLOOKUP(G2,'[jun_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4310,10,FALSE),
                        if(
                            B2=7,
                            VLOOKUP(G2,'[jul_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4322,10,FALSE),
                            if(
                                B2=8,
                                VLOOKUP(G2,'[aug_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4288,10,FALSE)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
```

As I mentioned in the comments, you are missing 3 closing parentheses and your `B2=5` `if` statement is missing a vlookup in the second "value if true" argument.

Try instead:

```
=if(
    B2=1,
    VLOOKUP(G2,'[Jan_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Sheet1'!$L$1:$U$4236,10,FALSE),
    if(
        B2=2,
        VLOOKUP(G2,'[feb_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$2:$U$4214,10,FALSE), 
        if(
            B2=3,
            vlookup(G2,'[mar_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4262,10,FALSE), 
            if(
                B2=4,
                VLOOKUP(G2,'[apr_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4262,10,FALSE),
                if(
                    B2=5,
                    Vlookup('[may_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4234,10,FALSE),
                    if(
                        B2=6,
                        VLOOKUP(G2,'[jun_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4310,10,FALSE),
                        if(
                            B2=7,
                            VLOOKUP(G2,'[jul_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4322,10,FALSE),
                            if(
                                B2=8,
                                VLOOKUP(G2,'[aug_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4288,10,FALSE)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Or:

```
=if(B2=1,VLOOKUP(G2,'[Jan_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Sheet1'!$L$1:$U$4236,10,FALSE),if(B2=2,VLOOKUP(G2,'[feb_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$2:$U$4214,10,FALSE), if(B2=3,vlookup(G2,'[mar_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4262,10,FALSE), if(B2=4,VLOOKUP(G2,'[apr_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4262,10,FALSE),if(B2=5,Vlookup('[may_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4234,10,FALSE),if(B2=6,VLOOKUP(G2,'[jun_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4310,10,FALSE),if(B2=7,VLOOKUP(G2,'[jul_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4322,10,FALSE),if(B2=8,VLOOKUP(G2,'[aug_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$4288,10,FALSE))))))))
```

Lastly, you may want to consider switching to `INDIRECT()` instead of the nested IFs. Your entire formula could be reduced to:

```
=vlookup(G2, INDIRECT("[" & TEXT(DATE(2000,B2,1),"mmm")) & "_Agent Hierarchy.xls]Agent Hierarchy Details'!$L$1:$U$5000"), 10, False)
```

Which is ugly in its own right, but gets you out of nested `if()` hell. `Indirect()` changes a string to a range. We use the number in `B2` to determine the month abbreviation, then use that to reference the sheet and range inside `Indirect()`. Then perform the vlookup on that range.

One of the caveats with that change is that you go into your Jan file and change the Sheet1 tab name to be `Agent Hierarchy Details` as you have with the other month files. One of the nice things about this change is that as new month workbooks are added the formula will automatically grab them.